# Classic ASP and ixsso.query returns EOF

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2, indexing-service

I have come across a bit weird problem with classic asp site which uses indexing service to search folder by given parameter and then lists files from the folder. Folder names are unique so the query should return only one recordset. Site is running at w2k8 64 environment. Before it was running in w2k3 server.

Basically everything runs okay but at some rare cases with specific folders query doesn't return anything at all. And this happens only if I go to the site from remote location. If I go to the site at localhost everything works just fine with those problematic cases.

Here is the code block

```
Dim strQuery
strQuery = "@all " & target & "*"
Set ixQuery = Server.CreateObject("ixsso.Query")
ixQuery.Query      = strQuery
ixQuery.Catalog    = "Reports" ' 
ixQuery.SortBy     = "create [d], filename [a]"
ixQuery.Columns    = "DocTitle, path, filename, size, create, directory"
ixQuery.MaxRecords = 150000
Dim util      
Set util = Server.CreateObject("ixsso.Util")
util.AddScopeToQuery ixQuery, Server.MapPath("Reports"), "deep"
Sim queryRS   ' Query recordset.
Set queryRS = ixQuery.CreateRecordSet("nonsequential")
```

Has anyone came up with same kind of problem? Any ideas how to solve it?

**Update: I rewroted the program in ASP.NET because it wouldn't work as classic asp.**

Comment: Same problem. I'd appreciate if you could post an ASP.net equivalent code of this ASP?